# How to access my variable in another function with in the scope

Tags: javascript

```
(function(){    
        pm.view.someFunction(arg) {
          arg is used here.
        }    

        pm.view.otherFun(){
          how can i pass the same arg here too
        }    
})();
```

how can i pass the same arg here in my other function. I heard that in closure we can access the variables which is above its context.

Comment: Are you sure? This isn't valid javascript.

Comment: How are `someFunction` and `otherFun` called?  Can't you just pass both of them `arg`?

Comment: BTW: `pm.view.otherFun(){` is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures mean that functions can use variables from their outer scope.  Here's an example:

```
function test(){
   var str = 'Hello',
   strFunc = function(){
     var s = str + ' world!';
     return s;
   };
   return strFunc;
}
var t = test();
console.log(t()); // Hello world!
```

The function returned by `test` (`strFunc`) is a closure.  It "closes" around the local variable `str`.  `str` is declared outside of `strFunc`, but since it's in the same scope, it can access it.

In your example, you just have two functions (one of which accepts an `arg` parameter), that are in the same scope.  `arg` is only in `someFunction`'s scope, `otherFun` can't access it unless it was passed as a parameter, or if `arg` was declared outside of the functions, like how `str` is declared before `strFunc` is.

Answer (score 1):

If arg is declared as a global variable, I do not see where the problem is.
If not, why don't you call `pm.view.otherFun` from within `pm.view.someFunction`?